# How to insert data into json from an html form

Tags: php, json

I was able to get the json file through this code:

```
<?php
include "lib/lib.php";

$url = "http://10.0.0.1/lib/api/desk/";

$params = array ("action" => "list","company_key" => "1");

$result=requestURL($url,$params);

$json_a=json_decode(strip_tags($result)); 
?>
```

The result of that is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "18",
            "name": "SM Quezon",
            "branch_address": "Quezon City, Philippines",
            "officer_in_charge": "Juan Dela Cruzz",
            "contact_number": "09321234567, 02-3449067"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a form which should function to add data array to a json file. What should happen is that after submitting the form, the inserted data will now be included in json file.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="form" onsubmit="alert('save?')" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" />
        <label class="control-label">Branch Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BranchAddress" />
        <label  class="control-label">Officer-in-Charge</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="OfficerInCharge" />
        <label  class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ContactNumber" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How will I be able to insert the data I have from the form to json file?

Comment: Great plan. What's your question?

Comment: @Ben how will I be able to insert the data I have from the form to json file?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the use. While the json data is there after the php file is parsed. It's not getting "Stored" anywhere for you to edit it. You will need to write this information back to your database to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the form: the "Save changes" button must be inside the `<form>` tag.

```
    <form>....
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes">
    </form>
```

Second step: inside the form you must add some fields.

```
<form>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
...
</form>
```

Third step: declare "action" and "method" on your form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

So at the end the form will be something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save changes">
</form>
```

**SAVE the INPUT FIELDS**

```
<?php
include "lib/lib.php";
$url = "http://10.0.0.1/lib/api/desk/";
$params = array ("action" => "list","company_key" => "1");
$result=requestURL($url,$params);
$json_a=(array)json_decode(strip_tags($result)); 

$newdata=array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $newdata[$key]=$value;
}
$json_a['data'][]=$newdata;

$json_a=json_encode($json_a);
?>
```

After that you will have a JSON object with included the new data. I suppose that you must save it somewhere.